# Convert enum to object with value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to create a helper that can return an object/enum like value so we're not repeating patterns:

```
enum ActionTypes {
    Find,
    Update,
    Create
}
enum RequestTypes {
    Request,
    Success,
    Failure

}
```

If i was starting with this enum here, I need a helper method that can convert this to the following:

```
const actions = createActions(ActionTypes);
// actions.Find.Request -> 'FindRequest'
// actions.Find.Success -> 'FindSuccess'
```

Not even sure where to begin i'm pretty novice at typescript

The full expected output of `actions` should be:

```
{
    Find: {
        Request: 'FindRequest',
        Success: 'FindSuccess',
        Failure: 'FindFailure'
    },
    Create: {
        Request: 'CreateRequest',
        Success: 'CreateSuccess',
        Failure: 'CreateFailure'
    },
    Update: {
        Request: 'UpdateRequest',
        Success: 'UpdateSuccess',
        Failure: 'UpdateFailure'
    }
}
```

Comment: so, `createActions` should combine the keys of two enums and pascal case them? Will the resultant object contain 9 properties?

Comment: That's correct @RameshReddy! I'll udpate the expected output

Comment: Are you open to using [string enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a type-safe functional solution that accepts two [string enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) as parameters (so you can reuse it for other cases):

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=68&ssc=69&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwKLIK4FsoF4oAlCAYwHt4ATAHgGcEVUAaKBpNAPgG4AoX0JCgA5CAwhUAwuRwAjFBLgcM2HDV5QoABSgQAHsAjIqdWIzSZczDVEm6DRk2eWWc1zgSgBvGwG0A0jooUADWECDkAGbaALoAXN42mgF2wWER0ZLxUIH2hsam7ExQAPw5dvr5TkVopVAABgAkXoEAvs3+kq31UAnIEABuEPC9UP1D8HyarXwz-JFYyKTAiOTIY2LAAILG0nIKSkyupuqaOpWOpocWqtaaFQ4Fzke3vJwAFEa4WgCG8EbABJaVhfHCSAAWiAANlQEpIAJQJUTiKQyeT9KjXFS4GjA2weHyaCjIBhQf50LBQwFQH7IECeLxzGyRShQd7E0npHRRKAAeVkACsyMAAHTpOifVS-f7IYDw+GJTSacmU4C+LkxBlzJVQFkjdlrTnhOw8-lC5Zi8IS0EQ6FUeWKnVksSq9XhLQxN0gLKeJpeLntf3G7pTJWtGzhmz-YBYeDrFVU2b8AD0yagAFU6BA4vxQcQIABHLCbAAq4GghPzRc2ngA5CRqwxa3dYFhSKQxKZCLWYG2O3Q6M2bAAxH7Q2PQbuj8f-IeR1N8iZQ8g-KgSXWLZardZr0hQv4-FZrNl7n4DxCkeEptMLJZH9akf6HiBbLeGqDqBdnPKXZ43Ky8F+tg-k8WKuNYC4fKC0oAkCIKqLaMJwoiIibBIezooo5jYmoeKSDwgE3pu95QI+EDPq+94nOcjxOGBqhQVKfywdoKHIoYqL7Bi9E4niggQDyDbFgwZaQARC63m+D5PoYlHbichFKjRVRXNh4GKfcIF0WpryQZK3zMbKcG6AhkIwiUyGJEB0axus-QMDsnGYTxODWkxMrAPBuCIVQpRlEJpblvCfALvOaa8kuK5rr5kkkfoYDknQ25shEWC1lCUJsBA0DAJChSgFC0CFQOUBRPkrCyFgwBQLlOUAO7kDS-y6EWiADD8hWylevActVZEUVJdAJJWuJaapLi3MBFygTpuCMQZHnGTaZmwrYbFoU5CiYrNuGsPhoajdN2kTXN+k4DBRmsUiG0YVtLm4qw-GCYWwnAKJEAEa0ng0A8Kl-jhrDKb+LkfDY0GGdSwJg6ZdoWbY1gKvgHj2dsuxogcO1uQtAJeWCK1+VWr3vcFuaqFAclrO9jrDigvlTrTQ6aOmYBUM+dbM6zhiM7YMmTlAtaSLzc78L1NKDZ4-WyYN7wU8gxPcFAC50D8ODQGepG87LEqy+9rABSJQV8By5CFSKy6oO8PyDSKgvkYYIq9u2nbBYraYAES28+jv9nQbs9YaJsQGb5AW1bVEuwutX2JAyzrgm1XkIKwpQMEqUjI2968EAA)

```ts
type StringEnum = Record<string, string>;

type NestedCombinedStringEnum<
  P extends StringEnum,
  C extends StringEnum,
> = {
  [KP in keyof P]: {
    [KC in keyof C]: KP extends string ? KC extends string ? `${KP}${KC}` : never : never;
  };
};

function nestAndCombineStringEnums <
  P extends StringEnum,
  C extends StringEnum,
>(enumParent: P, enumChild: C): NestedCombinedStringEnum<P, C> {
  const result: any = {};

  for (const keyP of Object.keys(enumParent)) {
    result[keyP] = {};
    for (const keyC of Object.keys(enumChild)) {
      result[keyP][keyC] = `${keyP}${keyC}`;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

// Use:

enum RequestType {
  Request = 'Request',
  Success = 'Success',
  Failure = 'Failure',
}

// Overloaded function declaration (classic)

// function createActions <
//   P extends StringEnum,
//   C extends StringEnum,
// >(enumParent: P, enumChild: C): NestedCombinedStringEnum<P, C>;
// function createActions <P extends StringEnum>(enumParent: P): NestedCombinedStringEnum<P, typeof RequestType>;
// function createActions <
//   P extends StringEnum,
//   C extends StringEnum,
// >(enumParent: P, enumChild?: C) {
//   return nestAndCombineStringEnums(enumParent, enumChild ?? RequestType);
// }

// Overloaded function expression (you'll see this style less often, but the two are equivalent)

const createActions: {
  <P extends StringEnum, C extends StringEnum>(enumParent: P, enumChild: C): NestedCombinedStringEnum<P, C>;
  <P extends StringEnum>(enumParent: P): NestedCombinedStringEnum<P, typeof RequestType>;
} = <C extends StringEnum, P extends StringEnum>(
  enumParent: P,
  enumChild?: C,
) => nestAndCombineStringEnums(enumParent, enumChild ?? RequestType);

enum ActionType {
  Find = 'Find',
  Update = 'Update',
  Create = 'Create',
}

const actions = createActions(ActionType); // same as createActions(ActionType, RequestType);
console.log(actions.Create.Success); // "CreateSuccess"
console.log(actions); // the expected result object in your question
```

Comment: This is great! I've tried to do this myself, however I wanted to have the `nestAndCombine` function a utility, and the RequestTypes will rarely change so I wanted to have a default value so when using the utility it's just 

`const actions = createActions(ActionTypes);` and if i need to overwrite the RequestTypes i can by passing the second argument

Comment: @ShannonHochkins Are you asking for me to update my answer with a curried function? If so, I'll do that. — Edit: Done. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thankyou, however this requires the createActions overloaded function to be in the same file we're declaring the ActionTypes, we basically wanted to import `createActions` and use it like you have, does this make sense?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins You said nothing about about modules in the question. I've answered your original question, and now you're asking a completely different question about JavaScript modules... What exactly do you want to know -- how to export a function and a type from a module and import it into another module? If you'd like to ask a different question about imports and exports and share a link to it here, I'd be happy to take a look, but on SO, each question should be about solving one problem at a time.

Comment: I did say create a helper, one would assume a helper is imported but that's okay, i'll ask another question, no need to be rude about it

Comment: @ShannonHochkins No rudeness was intended. (Context: many QAs here fall victim to [scope creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_creep) because OP doesn't state all requirements upfront). I think this was simply a matter of misunderstanding. I've updated my answer to swap the arguments of the curried function. I think that's what you are actually after. Working as intended now?

Answer (score 1):

you can get the enum strings from `Object.values` method then iterate and concatenate as you want.

```js
enum ActionTypes {
  Find,
  Update,
  Create
}
enum RequestTypes {
  Request,
  Success,
  Failure

}


function createActions(actionTypes) {


  let actionTypeStrings = Object.values(actionTypes).filter(e => typeof e == 'string');
  let requestTypeStrings = Object.values(RequestTypes).filter(e => typeof e == 'string');

  let actions = actionTypeStrings.reduce((a, c) => {

    let anAction: any = {};
    requestTypeStrings.forEach((e: any) => anAction[e] = c + e)

    a[c] = anAction;

    return a;
  }, < any > {})

  return actions;
}


const actions = createActions(ActionTypes);
console.log(actions);
```

Comment: This doesn't provide any intellisense when using the return of createActions

Comment: isn't provide you the expected results

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do:

```js
enum ActionTypes {
    Find = 'Find',
    Update = 'Update',
    Create = 'Create'
}

enum RequestTypes {
    Request = 'Request',
    Success = 'Success',
    Failure  = 'Failure'

}

type combination = {
  [k in  ActionTypes]: {
    [k1 in  RequestTypes]: `${k}${k1}`
  }
}


function createActions(): combination {
  return Object.keys(ActionTypes).reduce((cum, k) => {
     cum[k] = Object.keys(RequestTypes).reduce((cum1, k1) => {
       cum1[k1] = `${k}${k1}`
       return cum1;
     }, {} as any)
     return cum;
  } , {} as any)
}


console.log(createActions().Create.Failure)
// CreateFailure
```

TS Playground: https://tsplay.dev/WG6bkm

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a simple function to do this.

```
function mixEnumsToObject(e1: any, e2: any) {
  const keys1: string[] = Object.keys(e1).filter((key) => isNaN(Number(key)));
  const keys2: string[] = Object.keys(e2).filter((key) => isNaN(Number(key)));
  const mixEnumMap = new Map();

  keys1.forEach((key1) => {
    const valueObject = new Map();
    keys2.forEach((key2) => {
      valueObject.set(key2, key1 + key2);
    });
    mixEnumMap.set(key1, valueObject);
  });
  return mixEnumMap;
}

const mixedEnumObject = mixEnumsToObject(ActionTypes, RequestTypes);
console.log(mixedEnumObject);
```