# Return value of Enum typescript

Tags: typescript, types, enums

I have a helper method which converts an enum to a nested object, and also all the "values" of the object to a new type.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASsCOZgGcAuAVAngBxVA3gLABQUsCSaANCWQMpgDGjKyNpUAYgIYCWANmABOwdgF8SJVDmBQAwgHsIAI14hgAUXARkAHgAKVeQD4oAXgK0oAbQDS+qGqgBrYJgUAzKPoC6ALksOMjI7OUcQFzdPeX8oeyhgAA9UUAATZCg0ITUAcygAfjiwpJSQdMzUbJA8woADABJ8ezFG2zkxWqgA9QA3YCEuqF7+gG4rMTHiCcliaVwufm5UUsUVNU1tPUMTc0CQ+KdXdy9fAKIg4NDwyOOYgPiStIys3IKihOSniqqaqAam-QtJrtTrdYB9AZgiGTMhiaxHaJyHyTOEIk7ImYAegAVNjaNioAABEDcCCyRgiJbAACCjFQvAUIGQ+KJHjAIDpDJALMJqRQFN42HpjKgAAtgPxcAMwMhXowZaglORECgMDIMjzsNwhKSoNxOYysLgMgBaBLaKCMRmoPggV7uYR6g0ROYoTXa3UiFVoI14M0KIVc7j8PVCHKQUCoKCK8KMQR8y0KpVeyhR13IAB0PKSpOw-GALNAkCg6G4yjg3tQGXOUAJZAA8rgQOxa8E5PwFMgC6QCRIe+bi6XlLThUy9nWS2WWX3W1amVHrPrR2xo+qfLsKcAqSOucgABRDneMldDiup5AAShhBMxmKdy4zQ4zjdAUBNpgA5EOXyAPyzb-eu6PmWGbtp2sjvlAX5lmBXZ-v2AHprs0HKD+H5QAAPlBQ6wcA8GtoWFp0FuQiMKKR5jjWdacGoqT1uo07-neCgDLwXgOlAADu3AgGmChQAAVgqUAyrIqDihUPGpNqqTKqmvrMv2c5oDYS67kY6brhYm7bs6+6HnpV5MYBx4ZjRZT0cAGZnqqb6fuZdHqDZaD4Ted5qaZDmWRmDDMKwdlQV56i+SwyDIK5UAAR5TJmbR3k8AIwgQfZcXqAlggiBFiHqshQXAM5qDoVhH55SFrBFYFqXAOlSURYSIioMIY7WFokBGC81TWD465muJsgprZRbQFJUADSp6b4piMxJNgLFRmyHKjpalIpBRWzGHu0UKQE+gXgE1irKo6itToBgaTI0QFQpxgtlAe4dXkABkCxLCsShHRskBbOduCXRQqrXReGLECQM1zVAC3OstW6rXpZ0mJtzrbd4RhjWqxoBDxmC7Fd6p7TYh3rCd30mLd92VK8z2cIsyygITx2bPDcjGEDezBMpabqgED1dbsXUwuzx5RtFGQWPWygCcAdIZkc+5bXjGYiKkTDAHuiOMEY0W2G4F7mKYe41sEZAZib+oa1YRuLs62uYLE4uS9Lst7mjCkXorwDKywaterSGujQgNu62YpiG0bZAc5a73rLJFj-FrbhAl6NsdALYersaGbYDKop7laazqKkRkXEbDVNWzafGybPvMLdFc2EnbixHnH2pBbYfTMXUBiEY+BiBebd9z3fd6hkWOp-7jVCBEVvLj9wDRNTr101HDNfUzxg+OMkxDVAa3l1wVUkH2Ecz+p6coFp0O6cue5rUXiGirwGRP1xLHOK8HjrCQIuxRZ6hmXwDK3YAIKUyKKBQYB+CyWULIHiA5oCcUfmRRwGROJv1yEYZQYAoy8EtDxD881eDhhEFACBaYJKlynlAHowYkCkK8H1CG7JnQkGysaXKVUCoVRKlVMqYVuF5RqplIAA)

As you can see, the intellisense is working for the return values however i have an error trying to match the "enum" return value of "types", I'm not sure what to do here!

I've tried `typeof types`, `FlattenCombineEnums<P, C>`, `typeof FlattenCombineEnums<P, C>` as the return value but i'm getting no where.

This works: `(types as unknown) as FlattenCombineEnums<P, C>` however i don't think this is the right way of doing it!

Comment: In your playground, you seem to be wanting to return an array of strings, but your types currently indicate a union of string literals (which is just one string). Perhaps there is some confusion about the concepts of types and values? What kind of data structure are you wanting at index `1` of the array being returned from the function?

Comment: It also seems like this question is building on concepts from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70209488/438273). However, you've switched from using [String enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) to [Numeric enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums).